How to fix printer
HP Envoy 4520 will not print says Paused:rejecting jobs Ubuntu 24.04 Have tried to install each driver shown, but program will not take.

What does "program will not take" mean? Where are these drivers "shown"?

Have you installed hplip? Have you run hp-setup from the terminal?

nothing works, says printer status paused
